# WooCommerce dropdown issue after update

Tags: woocommerce

I have just updated to Woo Commerce 3.2.0 and my variations all worked fine before the update, now they’ve suddenly stopped working. They all show up on the Products page but when the Add To Cart button is clicked I get a message to say “Please choose product option”. Add to cart button is inactive as well.

Has anyone faced this? I wonder how to fix it.

P.S.: rollback to WC 2.6.1 reveal dropdonws on product page but all products missed. So, thus is not a way out.

Comment: Try looking in the theme "woocommerce" folder and check if you are overwriting the add to cart templates. I am guessing that you either overwrite the templates and they are outdated or there might be a JS error. Try with default theme, too

Comment: Thaks a lot!, will go this way

Comment: Its turned out that if the attribute name is on english or only numbers then dropdown works fine. But if I change the name in Russian language — dropdowns don't work.

Comment: It's the slug that is important, so I think that you can still show to customer Russian attribute, but keep the attribute slug in English